Does TikTok provide an API for accessing audience demographics and analytics data for accounts?
I am developing an application and I am looking for a way to access analytics data from TikTok, similar to the way Instagram provides analytics through Facebook and YouTube provides analytics via Google. Specifically, I am looking for an API that will allow me to access data such as audience demographics, engagement metrics, or media performance for TikTok accounts.
I’ve gone through the TikTok documentation, but I couldn’t find anything about an Analytics API for TikTok accounts.
Does TikTok offer an Analytics API for such data? If so, could anyone point me to the right documentation or resources on how to access it?
Thanks in advance for your help!
